# LeftNavBar creates black bar at the top of the activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar

I'm trying to incorporate Google's LeftNavBarLibrary into my application. When I load the nav bar I end up with a black bar across the top of the activity. The bar appears to be taking up the space a traditional actionbar would occupy.

Does anyone know where the bar is coming from or how to remove it.

Thanks.

[image]

My application theme is slightly customized. Based on the AppCompat theme due to requirements of the MediaRouteActionProvider

styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_gradient</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

The activity pictured above has a custom theme defined in the manifest.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name="my.app.namespace.CoreActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
</activity>
```

The applications minimum sdk version is 14. So it's not exclusively a Google TV app. I've only been able to test this bug on my Android 4.1 and 4.4 devices.

Comment: Why do you extend Theme.AppCompat if your app is targeting API >14 ? Have you tried to create a values-14 and put there a resources file that extends your app theme from Holo?

Comment: If you're trying to implement a left navigation bar like you would see in Gmail or G+, you should be using DrawerLayout from the support library. See http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: To answer both questions. I'm targeting the appcompat theme because from what I can tell the chromecast mediarouteactionprovider requires the appcompat libraries. The navigation drawer is a hidden UI that is not easy to get to with a d-pad driven interface. That's why I'm choosing to use googles lefthandnav library as it's tailored for the kind of navigation TV users expect.

Answer (score 2):

I deal with the action bar this way:

```
getActionBar().hide();
```

Try to put this in your main activity or the activity that is the parent and always present.
Don't bother about the theme in manifest, just set your theme with title bar and hide it through the code.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at: [Hide the Status Bar on Android 4.0 and Lower](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html#40)

Notice that this is in the `<application>` tag. That might help you.

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
    ...
</application>
```

or programmatically:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // If the Android version is lower than Jellybean, use this call to hide
        // the status bar.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set android:windowActionBar style to false by setting custom theme.
Note: In this case getActionBar() will return null. If you remove the action bar using a theme, then the window will not allow the action bar at all.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers guys. The real issue was actually that the LeftNavBar.java class was creating an artificial margin at the top of the screen. I'd have thought that a google published library would be better than that, but apparently not.